# push elements to object based on verifications

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

So, I have an object, thumbnailsAtivas, and I want to add elements to it, all of the same type, based on some verifications. If it already has the element `element`, it will return the first console log, then I loop through my object, and I want to know if there is any `thumbnail` inside my `thumbnailsAtivas` with the same `label` as the `element` and only then add the `element` to my object.

I've tried this, but the object returns always empty and I get the second console log. Im using react.

```
    if (this.state.thumbnailsAtivas.includes(element)) {
        console.log("already added")
    }
    else if (this.state.thumbnailsAtivas.map(thumbnail => {
        thumbnail.label.includes(element.label)
    })) {
        console.log("label already selected")
    }
    else {
        this.setState({thumbnailsAtivas: [...this.state.thumbnailsAtivas, textura]},
            () => console.log(this.state.thumbnailsAtivas));
    }
};
```

Comment: So, how is your thumbnailsAtivas structured? Does it hold objects?

Comment: Im initializing it has an emty array

Comment: Array of objects? If so I think you can't use `.includes` here.

Comment: So, with what should I work here ? I dont care about the position, I just need to find the string

Comment: @NelsonSilva You'll have to use either `some` or `every` to check existence of an object in an array of objects. How can you check if an object is the same as another object? Do they have like an ID or something unique to identify them? Also your first `else if` should use `some` or `every` too instead of `map` that you didn't write correctly.

Comment: `some`, `every` are for checking, `find` is for finding, `forEach` is for iterating, `map` is for `mapping`, `filter` is for filtering and `reduce` is for reducing. You can't use one array function to implement another's functionality. That's just bad, error prone code.

Comment: As @ibrahimmahrir you should use other methods for checking your element. Now, the new question is "how is your element structured?" Again as told, does it have an id or any other thing you can check?

Comment: `{name: "sheepskin", nameMaterial: "map_colour___swap", label: "Colour", index: "34", urlImage: "blob:http://localhost:3000/560c6d69-1a41-4740-b745-eca1024ca696"}`. This an example of an 'element', I may use the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, since you're checking the existence of the object in an array of object, you should use `some`:

```
if (this.state.thumbnailsAtivas.some(thumbnail => thumbnail.index === element.index)) {
    console.log("already added");
} else if (this.state.thumbnailsAtivas.some(thumbnail => thumbnail.label === element.label)) {
    console.log("label already selected");
}
else {
    // ...
}
```

Which means, you're basically checking if there is some `thumbnail` in `this.state.thumbnailsAtivas` that have the same `index` as `element`. And the same in the second `if`, for the `label`.

**Note:** Use `===` or `localeCompare` (whose result you'll have to invert as it returns `0` on success) to compare strings instead of `includes`. And add semicolons.

Comment: now I'm having problems with something related with your answer, if you could have a look and i would be very grateful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49909400/replace-object-in-array-base-on-index

Answer (score 0):

You mention that "thumbnailsAtivas" is an object, so will take it in the literal sense. ".includes" is a prototype that works specifically on arrays. To check your value try using "hasOwnProperty".

ie.

```
if(this.state.thumbnailsAtivas.hasOwnProperty('elementKey')) {  //code }
```